# Django - accessing Django Rest endpoint on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework

Very new to AWS and deploying my own projects/services in general. I deployed my first Django Rest API on Beanstalk.

I can access the application URL in the browser (`http://myappenv.someid.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/`, no problem.

However when I use that base url in my application on localhost, I get a `403: Authentication credentials were not provided.`

I am passing the DRF Token in the header, just like I normally would to access each endpoint. ie `http://myappenv.someid.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/mentions`.

When I switch back to a local version of the API in my application, I can access it normally.
My application is hitting the endpoint but, for some reason, even with the token passing, its returning the 403

my DRF is setup in settings.py as follows:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        #'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ) ,
   'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',)           

}
```

Any ideas? Would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) documentation, I have to adjust my  `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`